# How to read the data from AsyncData<void> in Riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, asynchronous, riverpod

I am trying to implement simple authentication using Riverpod package in flutter. State of my controller after calling the sign in function prints this: "AsyncData(value: Instance of 'Response')". How can I extract the body of response from this kind of data type?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```dart
/// A provider that asynchronously exposes the current user
final userProvider = StreamProvider<User>((_) async* {
  // fetch the user
});

/// or example
final userProvider = FutureProvider<User>((_) async {
  // fetch the user
});

class UserAuthenticationWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final AsyncValue<User> user = ref.watch(userProvider);

    return user.when(
      loading: () => CircularProgressIndicator(),
      error: (error, stack) => Text('Oops, something unexpected happened'),
      data: (user) => Text('Hello ${user.name}'),
    );
  }
}
```

Note [AsyncValueX](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/AsyncValueX.html). You can use any method that suits you.